# How to change the elements of multiple objects at the same time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity, and am making a top down game.
I have written a script that changes objects orders in the layer depending on whether the player is in front of or behind them, however I can't figure out how to  change all the objects' layers at once. (I tried making them all children of an object and it didn't work)
My current code looks like this;

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Perspective_changer : MonoBehaviour {
    void Update () {
        GameObject librarian = GameObject.Find("Librarian");
        Layer_orderer librarian_layer = librarian.GetComponent<Layer_orderer>();
        librarian_layer.y_pos = transform.position.y;
        GameObject blue_book_stand = GameObject.Find("Blue");
        Layer_orderer blue_book_stand_layer = blue_book_stand.GetComponent<Layer_orderer>();
        blue_book_stand_layer.y_pos = transform.position.y;
        GameObject purple_book_stand = GameObject.Find("Purple");
        Layer_orderer purple_book_stand_layer = purple_book_stand.GetComponent<Layer_orderer>();
        purple_book_stand_layer.y_pos = transform.position.y;
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Layer_orderer : MonoBehaviour {
    public float y_pos;
    void Start() {
    }
    void Update() {
        if (transform.position.y > y_pos)
        {
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sortingOrder = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sortingOrder = 3;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please don't post your codes as an image. You can add codes to your question.

Comment: Ok thanks I've changed it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use [FindObjectsOfType](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html) and do it in a loop

```
public class Perspective_changer : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private void Update () 
    {
        var layerOrderers= FindObjectsOfType<Layer_orderer>();librarian = GameObject.Find("Librarian");
        foreach(var layer in layerOrderers)
        {
            layer.y_pos = transform.position.y;
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: `FindObjectsOfType` only will find active and enabled components in the scene.

---

However as far as possible never use `Find` and `GetComponent` in `Update` or any repeating method since they are quite expensive. Rather do it once in `Awake` or `Start` and reuse the references. (I use the rule `Awake` for getting components and setting values of myself - `Start` for getting components/values from other components/GameObjects)

```
public class Perspective_changer : MonoBehaviour 
{
    Layer_orderer[] layerOrderers;

    private void Start()
    {
        layerOrderers = FindObjectsOfType<Layer_orderer>();
    }

    private void Update () 
    {
        foreach(var layer in layerOrderers)
        {
            layer.y_pos = transform.position.y;
        }
    }
}
```

The same also in `Layer_orderer`

```
public class Layer_orderer : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float y_pos;
    private SpriteRenderer _spriteRenderer;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // for single values this is easier to read/write
        _spriteRenderer.sortingOrder = transform.position.y > y_pos ? 1 : 3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a monobehavior on each of them, so each one updates themselves in Update().

Or use FindObjectsOfType() to get all of the SpriteRenderers.

BUT

There might be an easier way to do what you are trying to do.  You can change the transparency sort order axis in Edit->Project Settings-> Graphics.  Change it to a custom axis based on the Y coordinate.

[image: Sort axis settings]

Then, if you set your sprite's pivots to the ground when you import them, everything will just work.